# Find the maximum and minimum value of $\cos^2x-6\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\sin^2x+2$

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Find the maximum and minimum value of $$\cos^2x-6\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\sin^2x+2$$.

i simplified and reach to expression as follows :

$5 + 2\sin(x)[\sin(x)-3\cos(x)]$. How do i go from here?

Thanks

Comment: Can we use differentiation?

Comment: take $\frac{d}{dx}(\text{Your last expression})=0$

Comment: If not, there is a clear way to convert it into a linear combination of sin(2x) and cos(2x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression can be simplified to $$\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x +2\sin^2 x +2 -3\sin 2x $$ $$=3 -3\sin 2x + 2\frac {1-\cos 2x}{2} $$ $$=4 - 3\sin 2x - \cos 2x $$

Now we know that $$-\sqrt{a^2 +b^2} \leq a\sin \alpha + b \cos \alpha \leq \sqrt {a^2 +b^2} $$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: But how do i proceed from my solution or without changing to sin2x or cos2x

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos^2x-6\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\sin^2x+2$$
$$-3\sin(2x)+2\dfrac{1-\cos2x}{2}+3$$
$$-3\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)+4$$
now use
$$|a\sin\alpha+b\cos\alpha|\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Let $y=\cos^2x-6\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\sin^2x+2$

Divide both sides by $\cos^2x$ and use $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$

Now as $\tan x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\not<0$

Or divide both sides by $\sin^2x$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\cot x$

Comment: Aha, nice idea :)

Comment: I get y $\in [4+\sqrt10,4-\sqrt10]$. but how do i find max and min value in this interval?

Comment: @TaylorTed, You mean $$4-\sqrt{10}\le y\le4+\sqrt{10}$$ right? So, these the extreme two values of $y$

Comment: okay i was thinking if there was some point in middle of domian where y attains max. but i found range itself

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \cos^2x-6\sin(x)\cos(x)+3\sin^2x+2 &= -6 \cos(2 x) + 2 \sin(2 x)
\end{align}
$$

as a result of a simple differential calculation; now you'd like the $RHS$, namely $ -6 \cos(2 x) + 2 \sin(2 x)$, to be $0$ as to find the local minima and maxima of the function.

$$
\begin{align}
-6 \cos(2 x) + 2 \sin(2 x) &= 0 \iff \\
x &= \pi n + \arctan \big( \frac{1}{3} (-1 - \sqrt{10} \big) \bigvee \\
x &= \pi n + \arctan \big( \frac{1}{3} (-1 + \sqrt{10} \big) \\
\forall &n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
$$

From here you can find the absolute minima and maxima by several methods.